# Redux states modification is not reflected right after dispatch. Is dispatch async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have gone through the community and found many people saying the `dispatch` function in `redux` is synchronous. However, when I build the following app with `react-redux`, I find a bug seemingly due to the asynchronous behavior of my dispatch function. So I wonder what is the cause of the following codes and how to solve it (or perhaps replace the design pattern with better practices).

It is basically a part where

- user selects a value from a drop-down menu
- the app stores it in `states`
- the app reads from `states` and inquires an API with argument based on that state value the user chooses.

After I have chosen a value in the drop-down, the fetching raises an error of incorrect param format because my query URL is `example.com?param=undefined` (the initial state is `undefined`). When I select the second time there is no such format error (obviously, because the setting of `states` is finished at least once anyway and at least the param format is correct)

**Dropdown** (using `react-select`)

```
class Dropdown extends Component {
    onValueChange(v) {
        this.props.setSomeValue(v);
        this.props.queryData();
    }
    render() {
        return <Some-react-select-Dropdown
            value={this.props.someValue}
            onChange={this.onValueChange}
        />
    }
}

export default connect(state => {
    someValue: state.someValue
}, dispatch => {
    setSomeValue: dispatch(setSomeValue(v))
})
```

**App**

```js
class App extends Component {
    queryData() {
        fetch(`example.com?param=${this.props.someValue}`/*, ...*/).then(/*...*/)
    }
    render() {
        return <Dropdown
            queryData={this.queryData}
        />
    }
}

export default connect(state => {
    someValue: state.someValue.value // because react-select stores selected value in {label, value} format
})(App)
```

I expect the program to perform state-setting (via dispatch) and fetching synchronously, so that the query URL can be successfully generated. However (as is mentioned above), my choosing dropdown value for the first time makes the app to inquire an API with initial state of `undefined`.

Comment: Yes its true bcoz, setstate is asych and not get changed sudenly, you need to try callback

Comment: Changing Redux's store is like changing a component's state. It's asynchronous, so you can't expect the new values to be present on the next line of code.

Comment: It's true that dispatch is synchronous. But are you using any middlewares to make it async, Like thunk or saga?

Comment: @AshishKamble I assume so, and I know the `setState` function allows callback. But I am using the blackbox `dispatch` function provided inside `connect` from `react-redux`. I haven't found the documentation whether this function supports cb as well.

Comment: @Shan no I am not. Just `react`, `redux` and `react-redux`.

Comment: @fhfuih hi try using life cycle methods like `compnentwillreceriveprops` then check for `nextprops`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct to deduce that the value has not finished changing after executing your action here.

```
onValueChange(v) {
    this.props.setSomeValue(v); <-- creates action, updates redux-state
    this.props.queryData(); <-- executes before action above is complete.
}
```

The two functions you wrote are running to execution and not synchronously. You can workaround this by using the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method

Put this in your **Dropdown** Component

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.someValue !== this.props.someValue){
          this.props.queryData();
    }
}
```

So now you can run `queryData()` once it is confirmed that your `someValue` state has changed.